# Как создать плавающие ячейки в таблице?

Tags: html

Здравствуйте.

У меня на сайте ([Квазар](http://quasar.by/) нижняя часть) есть таблица, состоящая из 3 строк и 2 столбцов, в этих столбцах содержимое разного размера, то есть если содержимое небольшое, то образуется пустое место.

Можно каким-либо образом сделать, чтобы столбцы в таблице автоматически смещались вверх и между ними не появлялось пустое место?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем? Нормально все выглядит, заголовки и подчеркивание по уровню. Постарайтесь использовать рисунки одинакового размера и как-то заголовок стандартизировать, т.е. хоть это и неудобно, но размещать его на одинаковое количество строк.